# ASP.Net Core API DateTime with Time indicator issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API that takes in a date time as a query string.
Date is provided with a Time Zone indicator.
When I pass the date with with a "+"in time zone i am getting the default value of a Date Time.

I tried a very simple API that only takes a date from Query String a parameter.

When I pass the date

> 2019-03-12 07:00:00+05:00

I receive the error :

> "The value '2019-03-12 07:00:00 05:00' is not valid."

It looks like the "+"is not interpreted. With a "-" like

> 2019-03-12 07:00:00-05:00

It works well

It looks like we can't pass a "+" in a query string. 
How are you suppose to a pass date time with zone indicator in the query string  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to urlencode the `+`, since `+` means "space" in a URL. This should in fact happen for you automatically if you're using a tag helper or something like `Html.Action`, `Url.Action`, etc. If you're passing it manually, then it's on you to manually urlencode it.

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign in a query string means the space character. `%2B` is the URL encoded version of `+` and what you want.

Depending on where you are creating this URL, your can use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(...)` to escape any other characters that need this treatment, as well as the plus sign.